# Receiving 302 to notice page for https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full (Google Contacts API)

Tags: google-contacts-api

Our system allows users to sync their google contacts, which we process in a background job.  It has operated normally but over the weekend we got a lot of job failures and the response we got instead of the feed was a redirect to this notice:

> This page appears when Google automatically detects requests coming
>   from your computer network which appear to be in violation of the
>   Terms of Service. The block will expire shortly after those requests
>   stop. This traffic may have been sent by malicious software, a browser
>   plug-in, or a script that sends automated requests. If you share your
>   network connection, ask your administrator for help — a different
>   computer using the same IP address may be responsible. Learn more
>   Sometimes you may see this page if you are using advanced terms that
>   robots are known to use, or sending requests very quickly.

Is there a support specialist on Google's side that I can reach out to to help me figure out what specifically caused this notice and work with me to resolve how to keep it from happening in the future?  We have a large number of clients using this feature and if we've reach some upper limit it would be great to know what our options are.

**Update**

Here is the response:

`<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\">\n<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>302 Moved</H1>\nThe document has moved\n<A HREF=\"https://ipv6.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full%3Fmax-results%3D100000%26updated-min%3D2017-12-07T00:00:00%26&amp;q=EhAgAUgAeBkBBb52Tv_-BJs6GPGerdEFIhkA8aeDS6j2CxoQ_Hywc-NFGh247Y_7qycfMgFj\">here</A>.\r\n</BODY></HTML>`

Following the link takes you the the message I quoted above.

Comment: Can you show the full error response you have encountered in your post?

Comment: Google has services that you can call specifically meant to do things like this. Are you calling those, or are you using other methods?